# What is wrong with this query's select statement?

Tags: mysql

This Query produces the expected Result :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.AS_No SOURCE, b.AS_No TARGET, DATE(c.Time) as Time
FROM
    as_path a,
    as_path b,
    update_detail c
WHERE
    a.Update_ID = b.Update_ID
        AND a.Path_Index = b.Path_Index - 1 
        AND a.Update_ID IN (
            SELECT  Update_ID FROM (
                SELECT * FROM bgpstorage.announce_update t1 
                    JOIN (
                        SELECT IP as i, MAX(Update_ID) as maxupdate 
                            FROM bgpstorage.announce_update 
                                GROUP BY IP) x 
                                    ON t1.IP = x.i 
                                        AND t1.Update_ID = x.maxupdate) 
                                            sub) 
        AND DATE(c.`Time`) BETWEEN '2013-09-02' AND '2013-09-19';
```

However, I don't want the Time column to be in the produced table so i did something like :

```
SELECT SOURCE, TARGET FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
    a.AS_No SOURCE, b.AS_No TARGET, Date(c.Time) as Time
FROM
    as_path a,
    as_path b,
    update_detail c
WHERE
    a.Update_ID = b.Update_ID
        AND a.Path_Index = b.Path_Index - 1 
        AND a.Update_ID IN (
            SELECT  Update_ID FROM (
                SELECT * FROM bgpstorage.announce_update t1 
                    JOIN (
                        SELECT IP as i, MAX(Update_ID) as maxupdate 
                            FROM bgpstorage.announce_update 
                                GROUP BY IP) x 
                                    ON t1.IP = x.i 
                                        AND t1.Update_ID = x.maxupdate) 
                                            sub) 
        AND DATE(c.`Time`) BETWEEN '2013-09-02' AND '2013-09-19')tbl;
```

But this Query runs forever !!!

I also just tried to delete the Time from the Select but same thing. Whats the problem ?

Comment: `update_detail` is not joined with other tables, so you get row for each `update_detail` record...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these queries are identical (pretty much) but one takes forever and the other doesn't, there is a good chance that adding your outer select somehow confused the database's query optimizer. I would suggest taking a look at the 'explain plan' for these two queries - if they are significantly different, then you have your answer, and you need to work out (not sure if mysql has 'hints') how to get the explain plan back on track. If not, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas ;-)

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mysql+show+select+plan&oq=mysql+show+select+plan&aqs=chrome.0.57.7245&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=mysql+explain+plan

Comment: Also if queries are 'taking forever' and you kill them, very often the database server will carry on running them in the background, so after a few attempts the database is pretty much dead - check with a few simple queries that this isn't the case

Answer (score 0):

I can see several weeknesses in your query but I can't say what the results is going to be by moving things around.

1. Did you know that your SGBD has a lot of algorythims that precalculate the results according to the query structure? If you nest SELECT, it won't give the same search path. The extra select to remove 1 column is probably changing th search path by MySQL.
2. Since we are in the topic of search path, some SGBD allow you to save the search path and reuse the most optimized search path according to you so look out for that.
3. What is really time consuming in your case is the forced join in your first FROM statement.

   FROM
       as_path a,
       as_path b,
       update_detail c

This usually result in a really time consuming algorithm of joining all these table.

Try as possible to use the INNER JOIN key word that will ease the search path engine's work.

1. Another time consuming algoritm is the IN key word. Whenever the chance try to avoid a IN and replace it with a JOIN structure.
2. If you still have problems, replace nesting SELECT with temp table.